# What’s the probability that a hand of 5 cards has at least 2 spades?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

My thinking right now is that I need 4 cases. A case for getting a hand with 2 spades, a case for 3 spades, a case for 4 spades, and a case for 5 spades.

In order to find two spades in a hand would be $~{\tbinom{13}{2}\tbinom{39}{3}}/{\tbinom{52}{5}}~$ because we have two cards to choose from spades and three cards to choose from non-spades.

The other cases would be $~{\tbinom{13}{3}\tbinom{39}{2}}/{\tbinom{52}{5}}~$, $~{\tbinom{13}{4}\tbinom{39}{1}}/{\tbinom{52}{5}}~$, $~{\tbinom{13}{5}}/{\tbinom{52}{5}}~$  following the same logic. Then add all the cases in order to get the result.

$$\dfrac{{\dbinom{13}{2}\dbinom{39}{3}}+{\dbinom{13}{3}\dbinom{39}{2}}+{\dbinom{13}{4}\dbinom{39}{1}}+{\dbinom{13}{5}}}{\dbinom{52}5}$$

Comment: Mathjax hint: binomial coefficients can be printed using \binom{n}{k}: $\binom{n}{k}$

Comment: Or you could count hands with no spades, and hands with one spade.

Comment: \binom{39}{5}/\binom{52}{5} + \binom{39}{4}\binom{13}{1}/\binom{52}{5}  Something like that?

Comment: Your thought process and answer are both correct.  The answer in the comments counts the probability of "bad" hands, i.e. the complementary event, and so to find the final desired answer should be subtracted away from one.

Comment: Thanks guys appreciate the help.

Comment: To reiterate what Yasuda-kun said earlier, it does help readability if you type using MathJax in the future.  [Check out this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for information on how to do that.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that is okay.    You can also evaluate by way of the complement which, in this case, leads to an easier calculation load.

$$\mathsf P(N_\spadesuit\geq 2) {~=~ 1-\mathsf P(N_\spadesuit\leq 1) \\ ~=~ 1-\dfrac{\dbinom{13}{0}\dbinom{39}{5}+\dbinom{13}{1}\dbinom{39}{4}}{\dbinom{52}5} }$$